# Zeta function of abelian variety with CM

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

In his book, "Introduction to the arithmetic theory ..." (Ch 7, section 8) Shimura constructs the Zeta function of an abelian variety with CM and expresses it as a product of L-functions.

Since I found his proof of the main theorem of complex multiplication for elliptic curves very messy, (along with other proofs - and it's not clear that this one can be made simpler) I'd like to ask:

Are there other sources where the zeta function of an abelian variety is constructed (elliptic curve case is in Lang's Elliptic functions), or would you suggest learning this from Shimura?

Comment: There's a beautiful treatment in Section 7 of the paper of Serre-Tate (Annals 1968) assuming only the Shimura-Taniyama formula (ibid. p512). A proof of the Shimura-Taniyama formula can be found Tate's Bourbaki talk 352 using p-divisible groups, or in Milne's CM notes 8.1.

Comment: Brian Conrad's notes on complex multiplication give an algebraic proof of the main theorem of complex multiplication, including the Taniyama-Shimura formula and the application to L-functions of CM abelian varieties. They will be published as appendix A of the book 'CM Liftings' with Chai and Oort. There's a preprint available on his website